# Creating an SQL query to show clients and their contacts

Tags: sql-server, select, union-all

I am using SQL Server 2008. I have two tables:

**Clients**

```
CREATE TABLE Clients 
(
  Id int primary key, 
  Name varchar(20), 
  ParentId int
);

INSERT INTO Clients(Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (1, 'A', 1);
INSERT INTO Clients(Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (2, 'B', 2);
INSERT INTO Clients(Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (3, 'AA', 1);
INSERT INTO Clients(Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (4, 'BB', 2);
INSERT INTO Clients(Id, Name, ParentId) VALUES (5, 'C', 1);
```

This table contains all the clients' information, some of them have parent company/client and ParentId shows it. If it matches with the Id, it means that these clients are the top companies in the hierarchy.

**Contacts**

```
CREATE TABLE Contacts 
(
  Id int primary key, 
  Name varchar(20),
  Email varchar(20),
  ClientId int
);

INSERT INTO Contacts(Id, Name, Email, ClientId) VALUES (1, 'Bob', 'Bob@A.com', 1);
INSERT INTO Contacts(Id, Name, Email, ClientId) VALUES (2, 'John', 'John@A.com', 1);
INSERT INTO Contacts(Id, Name, Email, ClientId) VALUES (3, 'Charlie', 'Charlie@B.com', 2);
INSERT INTO Contacts(Id, Name, Email, ClientId) VALUES (4, 'Peter', 'Peter@AA.com', 3);
INSERT INTO Contacts(Id, Name, Email, ClientId) VALUES (5, 'Chris', 'Chris@AA.com', 3);
INSERT INTO Contacts(Id, Name, Email, ClientId) VALUES (6, 'Neil', 'Neil@BB.com', 4);
INSERT INTO Contacts(Id, Name, Email, ClientId) VALUES (7, 'Grant', 'Grant@C.com', 5);
INSERT INTO Contacts(Id, Name, Email, ClientId) VALUES (8, 'Cher', 'Cher@C.com', 5);
```

This table contains all the contacts for the specific client (`ClientId` shows it).

I need to have a list which contains clients and all the contacts of the specific client as well as all the contacts of his parent company.

For example

```
ClientName | ContactName  | ContactEmail
   AA      |              |
           |     Bob      |   Bob@A.com
           |     John     |   John@A.com
           |     Peter    |  Peter@AA.com
           |     Chris    |  Chris@AA.com
    C      |              |
           |     Grant    |  Grant@C.com
           |     Cher     |   Cher@C.com
```

I managed to write a SQL query which gives a result just for one client, but I want it to return more than one client. To show clients (3rd and 5th) and their contacts as above.

```
SELECT 
    C.Name, ' ', ' ' 
FROM 
    Clients C 
WHERE 
    C.Id = 3

UNION ALL

SELECT 
    ' ', Co.Name, Co.Email 
FROM
    Contacts Co
WHERE 
    ClientId = 3 OR (ClientId = (SELECT ParentId FROM Clients WHERE Id = 3))
```

Comment: Why do you need the data to have that exact format?

Comment: Can a child have child? What is the depth of a hierarchy?

Comment: Because that kind of request came from the user :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the formatting on SQL.

```
select
    Cli.Name,
    Co.Name,
    Co.Email
from Clients Cli
left join Contacts Co on
    Co.ClientId in(Cli.Id,Cli.ParentId)
order by
    1,2
```

With Formatting.. you really should do formatting outside SQL. But here is a way to do that

```
select
    CASE WHEN cls <> 1 THEN '' ELSE CLI_NAME END CLIENT_NAME,
    CO_NAME CONTACT_NAME,
    CO_EMAIL CONTACT_EMAIL
from (
    select
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
        PARTITION BY
            T.CLI_NAME
        ORDER BY    
            T.CO_NAME
    ) cls,
    CLI_NAME,
    CO_NAME,
    CO_EMAIL
    from (
        select
        Cli.Name CLI_NAME,
        '' CO_NAME,
        '' CO_EMAIL
        from Clients Cli
        WHERE 
            Cli.id in (3,5)
        UNION ALL
        select
            Cli.Name,
            Co.Name,
            Co.Email
        from Clients Cli
        left join Contacts Co on
            Co.ClientId in(Cli.Id,Cli.ParentId)
        WHERE 
            Cli.id in (3,5)
    ) T
) T
order by
    CLI_NAME,
    CO_NAME
```

Comment: Thank you. It is exactly what I wanted. Just a question: where to add a clause: WHERE C.id = 3 or C.id = 5 (to select 3rd and 5th client?)

Comment: @shummis added where clause

Answer (score 0):

You could use a UNION to get the parent company data as well, provided that clients only have one parent company and this isn't recursive. I would format the data as required within your reporting tool rather than try to do this in SQL.

```
SELECT
  Clients.Name AS ClientName,
  Contacts.Name AS ContactName,
  Contacts.Email AS ContactEmail
FROM
  Clients
JOIN
  Contacts
ON
  Clients.Id = Contacts.ClientId

UNION

SELECT
  Clients.Name AS ClientName,
  Contacts.Name AS ContactName,
  Contacts.Email AS ContactEmail
FROM
  Clients
JOIN
  Contacts
ON
  Clients.ParentId = Contacts.ClientId

ORDER BY
  ClientName,
  ContactName
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is  a generic solution ( without formatting) which allows a child to have child/ hierarchy depth >1

```
  WITH parentcte (id,parentid,name)
  AS (SELECT c1.id,
 c1.parentid,name
  FROM clients c1
 WHERE c1.id=3 -- you can remove the where clause if you want list of all clients
  UNION ALL
  SELECT
    c.id,c.parentid,parentcte.name
  FROM parentcte
  JOIN clients c
    ON 
    c.id=parentcte.parentid where c.id != c.parentid)
    select  distinct p.name,con.name,email from parentcte p
    join contacts con on con.ClientId=p.id or con.clientid=p.parentid
```